# Table in *.CSV file first columns are empty

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I have a *.csv file with some data. It must be opened and saved with datagridview. Problem is - I have 1 column empty after file is saved.

*Please refer image for more details*

[image: csv file screenshot]

I need first column not empty and defined item count as int.

I need to define "Item Count" as int otherwise it will not sort correct.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ITApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

         DataTable table = new DataTable();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            table.Columns.Add("Item Code", typeof(string)); 
            table.Columns.Add("Item Description", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Item Count", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("On Order", typeof(string));

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }

        private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Stockfile\stocklist.csv");
            string[] values;

            for(int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                values = lines[i].ToString().Split(',');
                string[] row = new string[values.Length];

                for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
                {
                    row[j] = values[j].Trim(); // split the current line using the separator
                }

                table.Rows.Add(row);

            }
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
            int count_row = dataGridView1.RowCount;
            int count_cell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 0; j++)
                        {

                            writer.Write("," + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
                        }
                        writer.WriteLine("");
                    }
                    writer.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Done!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing a comma at the start of every line, so there is a blank in column 1.

One solution would be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 0; j++)
{
    if (j>0) writer.Write(",");
    writer.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
}
```